# Bash, grep sentence from file

Tags: bash

I have made a simple answering machine in bash. Basically if you greet it, it will greet you back but now I have a problem with sentence analyzing.
If the sentence ($@) is more than one word, it fails.

```
if [[ "$@" = $(grep -Fx "$@" 'vocabulary/greeting') ]]
        then
            speak greeting
        elif [[ "$@" = $(grep -Fx "$@" 'vocabulary/appreciative') ]]
```

The output:

```
> hello
Sam:  Hi!
> how are you
grep: are: No such file or directory
grep: you: No such file or directory
grep: are: No such file or directory
grep: you: No such file or directory
grep: are: No such file or directory
grep: you: No such file or directory
grep: are: No such file or directory
grep: you: No such file or directory
grep: are: No such file or directory
grep: you: No such file or directory
Sam:  I don't understand.
>
```

How do I fix this?
How can I catch possible errors like these in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `"$*"` instead of `"$@"`.

```
if [[ "$*" = "$(grep -Fx "$*" 'vocabulary/greeting')" ]]
```

`"$*"` is a string representation of the arguments, while `"$@"` is an array.

Comment: While this could work for OP, note that this approach will swallow up all white spaces to a single space. So, `./script How<space><space><space>are<space><space>you` will become `./script How<space>are<space>you`. Probably that's what OP wants, in order to grep easily.